# Inserting blank rows in active cell visual basic excel

Tags: excel, vba

When I click a button, I want to add3 rows after a cell which has content. How can i improve my codes below? for the first 3 rows, there are  already contents in the cells. i tried to copy the 3 rows then just erase it contents. my problem is if i already put datas in row 4 to row 6, then i click the button again, the previous row 4 to row 6 will now move down, the new blank rows will always be inserted after row 1-row 3 which is not what i want. The 1st 3 rows has a format that's why i copied it first. I want the format of the first 3 rows also to be copied but not the contents, just blank rows.

```
Sub newRow()
        Rows("1:3").Select
        Selection.Copy
        Selection.Insert shift:=xlDown
        Range("4:6").ClearContents
End Sub
```

Comment: surely the rows below are already blank? Or do you have rows of data, with blank cells in between? Also, you shouldn't need to copy or use `Selection`, just use the `Range` object.

Comment: [check this out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16519178/excel-vba-insert-a-rows-based-on-specific-cell-value/16523444#16523444) [excel-vba-insert-a-rows-based-on-specific-cell-value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16519178/excel-vba-insert-a-rows-based-on-specific-cell-value/16523444#16523444)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
Range("1:3").copy
range("4:6").pastespecial paste:=xlpasteformats
```

will copy the **formats only** from rows 1 to 3 to rows 4, 5 and 6

so if row 3 has a colour, then row 6 will have that colour.

If you want to make it dynamic you would need to determine the last row with content:

```
Activesheet.usedrange.rows.count
```

will return the number of used rows *including rows that have formats but no content* (I just tried it)

then you just plug that into your copy paste code:

```
Dim lngLastRow As Long

lngLastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
Range(lngLastRow - 2 & ":" & lngLastRow).Copy
Range(lngLastRow + 1 & ":" & lngLastRow + 3).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
```

try that in the **event handler** for your button

Comment: it works but i want it to still work every time i click a button, not just apply to row 3 and 4.

Comment: is it easier when i just choose an active cell then it will insert 3 rows below this active cell? how about that?

Comment: @Philip +1 for understanding the question! +1 for the answer!